# vector< pair<aStruct*,int> > not possible?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, std-pair

So I tried to make a vector which elements are pairs of a struct pointer and an int, and I'm beginning to think that this may be impossible..

Suppose I have the following struct:

```
struct node{
  string str;
  int size;
  node *child[3];
  node(string str1):str(str1){ size = 0;}
};
```

and a vector:

```
vector< pair<node*,int> > nodvector;
```

Then I tried to make a new node and put it in the vector, and apparently it's not working:

```
int main(){
   node* nod1 = new node("HELLO");
   node* nod2 = new node("WORLD");
   nodevector.push_back(pair<nod1,3>);
   delete nod1;
   delete nod2;
}
```

The compiler barks at me saying:
nod1 cannot appear in a constant-expression
error: template argument 1 is invalid
error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for template struct std::pair

Is this just something impossible?
What could be an alternate solution to this?
Your input will be so much appreciated!

Comment: You have to read some tutorial of c++.

Comment: try not to store bare pointers in a container. It is hard to do correct memory management this way.

Comment: when creating the pair to add it in the vector, you should give back the template arguments like this pair<node*,int>(nod1,3)
Usually, you do a typedef of it

Comment: Besides your the problem you asked about, and all the other (pointer related) problems that were raised in the answers your constructor should take a `const string&` instead of a mutable string. (In the general case this will save a copy, and more importantly it is more correct, robust and easier to reasohn about)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nodevector.push_back(pair<node*,int>(nod1, 3));

Answer (score 8):

When you create new pairs, use `make_pair` instead.

So this works: `nodevector.push_back(make_pair(nod1, 3));`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using `nod1` and `3` as the template parameters to pair in:

```
nodevector.push_back(pair<nod1,3>);
```

Instead, try:

```
nodevector.push_back(pair<node, int>(nod1,3));
```

Or better yet:

```
nodevector.push_back(make_pair(nod1,3));
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers are correct.

Your code is trying to push a "type" into a vector. That is why the compiler is angry:).

You are doing something like

```
int i = 10;
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(int);
```

Obviously, you want

```
v.push_back(i);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of pair. You haven't created it yet.

Do you think "pair" is right syntax ?

Correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this you are confusion you template argument for the accrual class to be operated on.

```
vector< pair<node*,int> > nodvector;
```

node* nod1 = new node("HELLO");
   node* nod2 = new node("WORLD");
   nodvector.push_back(pair(nod1,4));
   delete nod1;
   delete nod2;
}

Answer (score 0):

As of C++11, a much cleaner alternative to `nodevector.push_back(pair<node*,int>(nod1, 3));` or even `nodevector.push_back(make_pair(nod1, 3));` is using [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back). `std::vector<T>::emplace_back` will take the same arguments as `T`'s constructor(s), so you can enter the parameters directly:

```
nodevector.emplace_back(nod1, 3);
```

If you still feel the need to use `push_back`, as of C++17 class template arguments can be deduced, so you don't have to use `make_pair`:

```
nodevector.push_back(std::pair{nod1, 3});
```